# How to get headers data from http request in angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have just started with angular. I am facing difficulty in accessing headers from http request in my angular application.

After OpenSSO authentication , application opens homepage which has homepagecontroller. I am not able to get the headers data from $http in homepagecontroller.

For example: In servlets, we get the headers from httpservletrequest like :

HEADER_NAME=request.getHeader("uid");

So, How can we get the headers data in angular controller?

Comment: did you tried `$http.get('/someUrl').then(function(response) {
     response.headers() // this will return you object of your Request headers 
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  })`

Comment: i don't understand what url i have to put, after authentication the application homepage is open. So, should i give that in url?

Comment: u are using `$http` right ?

Comment: @Rahul yes i am using $http

Comment: then in that u must me passing url right ? in same callback function u need to call `response.header()`